# tikzscale with tikz-external: Recreating plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzscale, external

I am creating pgfplots in the tikzpicture-environment together with the external library. To ensure the width of the plot, I wanted to use tikzscale.

Originally, I was using the beamer-class with a custom template. With this config, external does not work any more and the picture gets recreated everytime.

I use texlive 2015 with  `pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex`

I started creating a MWE, but with the plain beamer-class it works.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-shell-escape]
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{imagefile.tikz}
\end{document}
```

If I change it to article and keep `[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]`, it does not. If I change width+height to a fixed length, it works again.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-shell-escape]
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=10cm]{imagefile.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Where does this behavior come from and how can I use \textheight+\textwidth with this combination? Maybe this is a bug and relates to [this issue](https://github.com/MagicMuscleMan/tikzscale/issues/3)?

imagefile.tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```